# Parameter portrait=true doesn't work for Google Sheets Publishing PDF functionality

Tags: google-sheets

I have published one of my sheets to download it in pdf:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSltr5HBmYtYSYoMeOdzk0G7LDbu430OXD8dMbX47BJq-qrXGRqAi0o_AB888VFaw6SDx/pub?gid=1095430144&single=true&output=pdf

I'm trying to change the pdf orientation using portrait=true URL parameter like this:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSltr5HBmYtYSYoMeOdzk0G7LDbu430OXD8dMbX47BJq-qrXGRqAi0o_AB888VFaw6SDx/pub?gid=1095430144&single=true&output=pdf&portrait=true

But it doesn't work.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

### Use the export link instead of publishing to the web

Since you want to convert your sheet to a pdf and download it instead of opening it in the browser, you can simply export it.

- The export URL accepts the `portrait=true` parameter.
- The export URL would look as following:
  `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/FILE_ID/export?exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf&portrait=true`
- Keep in mind that `FILE_ID` is the file id that you can find in the sheet URL:
  `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/FILE_ID/edit#gid=0`
- `FILE_ID` is different than the publishing to the web id (the latter starts with `2PACX-`)
- When exporting the sheet as pdf, `portrait=true` is actually not necessary, because the sheet will be exported as portrait by default